# How to change a variable with an if statement

Tags: javascript, variables, if-statement

So I'm trying to have a difficulty setting in a game I'm making in JavaScript. The hard mode has a shorter timer. I've tried shortening the time remaining variable with an if statement but it doesn't change the timer in the game.

```
<input type="checkbox" id="cb2" value="yes"> Hard

<script>
var timeRemain = 10;

if (document.getElementById("cb2").checked){
    timeRemain == 5;
} else {
    timeRemain == 10;
}
function countdown() {
    var timerId = setTimeout(countdown, 1000);
    if (timeRemain == 0) {
        clearTimeout(timerId);
    } else {
        timeRemain--;   
        document.getElementById("timer").innerHTML = timeRemain + ' seconds left!';
    }
}
</script>
```

I'm still very new to JavaScript so I'm aware I might be doing this completely wrong.

Comment: Where is `countdown` called? Where is `var timeRemain = 10` initialised? Please post a [mcve] with valid syntax, not a mix of JS and HTML.

Comment: You have spaces around the `=` in your HTML attributes - they shouldn't be there. Next, it's time for some basic debugging. The question isn't: why isn't the variable being set? The question is: is my condition resolving to what I think it does? Put an alert inside the condition and see if it fires.

Comment: Try putting the time remaining in a function and call it when key actions are taken.  Use the function to modify the timeRemaining variable.  Calling the function when an action is performed will probably solve the problem.

Comment: It seems that you are not placing your JS code within `<script>` tags. That is one place to start :) You can not mix HTML and JavaScript like this.

Comment: Dont confuse `=` assignment with `==` comparison! (`timeRemain == 5;` ?!)

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure it's supposed to be `timeRemain = 5` and not `timeRemain == 5`, since single `=` means assign value while two or three are for comparison.

```
if (document.getElementById("cb2").checked){
    timeRemain = 5;
} else {
    timeRemain = 10;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

## Code :

```js
var timeRemain = 10;

if (document.getElementById("cb2").checked)
    timeRemain = 5;
 else
    timeRemain = 10;

countdown = () => {
    var timerId = setTimeout(countdown, 1000);
    if (timeRemain == 0) 
        clearTimeout(timerId);
     else {
        timeRemain--;   
        document.getElementById("timer").innerHTML = `${timeRemain} seconds left!`;
    }
}
```

```html
<input type="checkbox" id="cb2" value="yes"> Hard
```

---

## Edits :

- You were using `timeRemain == 5` and same for `timeRemain == 10` changed
- Changed code function declarations a little too (using arrow function now)

---

## Materials :

- [Arrow function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions)
- [Comparison operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Comparison_Operators)
- [Assignment operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Assignment_Operators)

---

## Note :

- You are not calling the countdown function
- Time remain is not initialized at all

---